# Writing a sum function in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typeerror

**EDIT: Of course there are other implementations of the sum function, in particular some where the problem doesn't arise, but my question is really about this specific one.**

The following function in TypeScript computes the sum of an array of numbers:

```
function sum(list: number[]): number {
    if (list.length > 0) {
        const el: number = list[list.length - 1];
        list.pop();
        const s = sum(list);
        return s + el;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

It would be more convenient to write it like that:

```
function sum(list: number[]): number {
    if (list.length > 0) {
        const el: number = list.pop();
        const s = sum(list);
        return s + el;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

This produces a Type error:

```
Type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

This is because, when list is empty, `list.pop()` is undefined. But because of the if-condition, list is not empty in that line. Why doesn't TypeScript recognize that? The same error appears when I replace the if-condition with `if (list.pop())` and `if (list.pop()!==undefined)`.

How to fix this in the most elegant way?

Comment: This does not  directly answer your question, but I think it will be better to use `Array.reduce` for this purpose.

Comment: @wentjun Of course there are other implementations of the sum function, in particular some where the problem doesn't arise, but my question is really about this specific one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add the non null assertion operator to fix this problem.

```js
function sum(list: number[]): number {
    if (list.length > 0) {
        const el: number = list.pop()!;
        const s = sum(list);
        return s + el;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

This enables TypeScript to convert it to a `number` and not `number | undefined`. It simply means to the compiler, that this will not be `undefined` or `null`

Comment: This is very useful, thanks! And here is the reference: 
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator

Answer (score 1):

This is a known design limitation in TypeScript. TS will not infer the type for `Array.prototype.pop` even if you setup a type guard like check for the length of the array in a conditional statement.

For reference see github [issue#30406](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30406)

A solution, if you are sure of what you are doing you can use type assertion to explicitly set the type for the value.

```js
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

if (array.length > 0) {
    const el = array.pop() as number;
}
```

***Now to the second issue***
`Array.prototype.pop` will mutate the original array. For example if you remove the last element using `.pop()` from an array passed as argument in your function, the last element will be removed permanently from the array which will be lead to some nasty errors if some other part of the program needs the array to function properly

```js
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

function removeLast(list) {
  list.pop();
}

removeLast(array) // will mutate the array

console.log(array)
```

If you all you need to find the sum of all the numbers in an array, consider using `Array.prototype.reduce` or some other iterative solution instead.

Example,

```js
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

// using forEach
let sum = 0;
array.forEach(el => {
 sum+=el
});
console.log("Sum of numbers using forEach:", sum)

// using reduce
const result = array.reduce((acc, cur) => acc+cur, 0);

console.log("Sum of numbers using reduce:", result)
```

Comment: Thank you, the part "as number" is very useful.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use a simple iterative function :

```
function sum(list: number[]): number {
  let result: number = 0;
  for (let i=0; i<list.length; i++) {
      result += list[i];
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Of course there are other implementations of the sum function, in particular some where the problem doesn't arise, but my question is really about this specific one.